# What's the difference between (cast)variable and ((cast)variable)

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following code:

T imageCollectionItem;

```
// This checks if image actually exists, if it doesn't it gets the next best one... Thumbnail wil always exist so it will always find one
imageCollectionItem = (this.ResizedImageCollection
    .Where(x => ((IBaseImage)x).Image.ImageSizeType.Key != ImageSizeType.Original)
    .OrderByDescending(x => ((IBaseImage)x).Image.ImageSizeType.Key == imageSizeTypeKey)
    .ThenBy(x => ((IBaseImage)x).Image.ImageSizeType.Order)
    .FirstOrDefault());

if( imageCollectionItem != null )
{
    return ((IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem).Image; // Compiles fine
    return (IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem.Image; // Fails
}
```

What's the difference between `(cast)variable` and `((cast)variable)`?

**Considering one compiles and one doesn't?**

Comment: `(cast)variable` has been wrapped to access the property of type `cast`. if not wrapped in round bracket then it would have only access to the properties of type variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( imageCollectionItem != null )
{
    return ((IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem).Image; // Compiles fine
    return (IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem.Image; // Fails
}
```

The first line runs because the `.Image` is run on an object that has been cast to the correct interface.

In the second line, you are not casting it until *after* calling the `.Image` property -- which I assume results in a "Member not found" error or similar.

Answer (score 3):

There is an order of precedence for operators. Cast is in the Unary "block", while member access is in the Primary "block". Primary block has more priority than Unary block. First the Primary block operator (member access) would be executed, then the cast operator (Unary block). Clearly the member access can't be executed because the type is wrong. Compilation error.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx and (newer) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx .

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Newer link with more operators :-)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't compile:

```
(IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem.Image;
```

because of the [order of precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) of the [cast-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx)(Unary) and the [dot operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zhxzbds.aspx)(Primary). The former has a lower precedence than the latter. For that reason the compiler tries to execute this statement first:

```
imageCollectionItem.Image
```

That doesn't compile because `imageCollectionItem` is not an `IBaseImage` at this point.

By wrapping it in parentheses you tell the compiler that it should execute this as a block before the dot-operator is executed:

```
((IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem).Image // an IBaseImage now
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ((IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem).Image;
```

In this return-statement, only imageCollectionItem will be casted to IBaseImage.

```
return (IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem.Image;
```

The whole return-statement will be casted.

Answer (score 0):

```
((TypeX)ObjectA).PropertyOfTypeX; // Compiles fine
```

because you first convert ObjectA to TypeX and then refer to property PropertyOfTypeX

```
(TypeX)ObjectA.PropertyOfTypeX; // won't work
```

because you try to access property PropertyOfTypeX before you convert ObjectA to TypeX. In this case you tried to convert PropertyOfTypeX from ObjectA to TypeX. PropertyOfTypeX doesn't exists on ObjectA in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down these two statements and see what exactly they are trying to do. This way it will be simple to see that the second statement is trying to access the property before casting.

First,

```
// return ((IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem).Image; // Compiles fine
var casted = (IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem; // cast to IBaseImage
return casted.Image; // access the Image property
```

Second,

```
//  return (IBaseImage)imageCollectionItem.Image; // Fails
var noCast = imageCollectionItem.Image; // doesn't work becuse Image is not a memebr of imageCollectionItem
return (IBaseImage)noCast;
```